# How to clear all Evince bookmarks?

Tags: evince, bookmarks

Is there any quick way to clear all Evince bookmarks? The interface only allows selecting and removing one at a time. Manually editing `~/.local/share/gvfs-metadata/home` to remove the bookmarks lead to resetting everything, not just the bookmarks.

This is for the case in which there are a lot of bookmarks so clearing manually would take a long time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bookmarks are stored as a [`gio` file attribute](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/gio-GFileAttribute.html#gio-GFileAttribute.description), e.g. you can list them with

```
gio info -a metadata::evince::bookmarks myfile.pdf
```

Setting that attribute to empty string will remove all bookmarks from your document:

```
gio set myfile.pdf metadata::evince::bookmarks ''
```

---

<sup>Note this is rather new stuff - it replaces `gvfs-info` and respectively `gvfs-set-attribute` (with similar syntax)</sup>

Comment: I used `gvfs-set-attribute myfile.pdf metadata::evince::bookmarks ''` since I could not figure out which package gio is part of. I am using XFCE on NixOS and am thinking it might require installing some Gnome components.